# responsive theme disable virb

Tags: mobile, resize, themes

If someone can help me with this I will be eternally grateful. Recently I have started an on-line magazine using virb.com to host the site. I have done some basic css alterations to their theme but run into a problem when the theme automatically re-sizes itself for mobiles or even if the browser window is shrunken down. The content goes all whack, probably because of my css alterations. Is there a way that I can disable the responsive theme from resizing or fix my css so it doesn't discombobulate or even just have different page display for mobile users that says something like 'not available for mobile'??

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: sorrry forgot to add the link to the website www.tryhardmagazine.com

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm helping a designer friend out with a Virb site and I tried adding some custom `css` with `media-queries` but Virb stripped out the `media-query`.